# Understand healthy, secure, and "proceed straight" in context

Tags: word-meaning

**Text:**

> To buy your first home, you likely will need a mortgage. In fact, before you even start looking at houses, you should look into your mortgage prospects.If you have good credit, a **healthy** income and money in the bank, you’ll be able to **secure** mortgage preapproval quickly and **proceed straight** to the homebuying process. But if you have less-than-stellar credit, are self-employed or have little cash to bring to the table, you’ll want to start the process way before you look at houses – maybe more than a year before.

**Questions:**

1. Does the adjective **healthy** in financial contexts mean **sure**? In this case, based on my perception it means a sure and coming-every-month income.
2. Does the word **secure** here mean **gain** ?
3. When saying **proceed straight**, does it mean **to go in that way straight**?

Answer (score 1):

These are all figurative meanings.

No, *healthy* means *robust*, not merely steady. It means "steady and sufficiently large".

*Secure* here means "to obtain" or "to get".

*Proceed straight* means to "continue directly", without taking any detours or encountering any delays.